# How to copy attributes from one to another object with TYPO3 Extbase?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

With `Tx_Extbase_Property_Mapper::map()` ("the old property mapper") it was possible to copy attributes from one to another object:

```
$propertyMapper = t3lib_div::makeInstance('Tx_Extbase_Property_Mapper');
$propertyMapper->map(array('senderAddress', 'recipientAddress', 'subject', 'body'), $oldObj, $newObj);
```

With the "new" property mapper the `map()` method does not exist any longer.

Is there a working/elegant possibility to copy attributes from one to another object within Extbase?

Comment: I don't think an equivalent exists as far as I understood? What exactly do you want to achieve? Just that the given array of properties from $objA will be copied to $objB? (which would not involve any mapping) Or do you need some kind of resolution (like senderAddress on A is field foobar on B?)

Comment: @Susi I stumbled over it while upgrading an TYPO3 extension from TYPO3  4.5 to 7.6: in the Extension `Tx_Extbase_Property_Mapper::map()` was used to set some attributes of a newly created object with attribute values of an existing object (of the same type). I guess as long as there exists a getter and a setter for every attribute, @froemken's snippet will do the job. By now I am not sure if using `Tx_Extbase_Property_Mapper::map()` or @froemken's solution (although it works fine) is even necessary (for my usecase) – I think I prefer calling the getter and setter for each property explicitly.

Comment: Calling the getter and setter is preferable if possible - at least to me. It seems a lot cleaner and more explicit (no magic involved ;)).

Comment: @Susi Thank you for your opinion on "explicit" vs. "magic".

Answer (score 3):

No. Not within extbase, but you can build your own method like this:

```
$properties = array('senderAddress', 'recipientAddress', 'subject', 'body');
foreach ($properties as $property) {
  $getter = get . ucfirst($property);
  $setter = set . ucfirst($property);
  $newObject->{$setter}($oldObject->{$getter}());
}
```

Comment: I suggest using `ObjectAccess::getProperty` and `ObjectAccess::setProperty` so you don't have to assume that all your getters are prefixed "get" (also supports "is" for bools!). See also `getGettableProperties` on same class!

Comment: Based on code by @ClausDue I made a clone service that creates copies of objects including all relations. It also handles lazy loading related objects and you can set for each property if it must be cloned, referenced or ignored. Code was for TYPO3 4.7 and is probably a bit long to post here. If you're interested …

Comment: Current community version of code mentioned by @JigalvanHemert - https://github.com/nikonierer/tool/blob/master/Classes/Service/CloneService.php - though I'm not sure this version of the CloneService is the same as the one Jigal worked on.

Comment: Functionality-wise almost the same. In the `copy` function after the line `$originalValue = $object->$getter();` it needs one thing the make it work for lazy loading properties: `if ($originalValue instanceof Tx_Extbase_Persistence_LazyLoadingProxy) {
     $originalValue = $originalValue->_loadRealInstance();
    }` (formatting is lost in a comment)

Comment: Be aware, that you can not just clone `ObjectStorage` objects using `ObjectAccess::getProperty` and `ObjectAccess::setProperty`. Best here is to create a new object of type `ObjectStorage` and add all items manually before setting it with `ObjectAccess::setProperty`